# Copying data from 1st to 2nd array using Pointer arithemtic

Tags: c, arrays, function-pointers, void-pointers

I am learning C, and I came across this problem I can't figure it out. Write a function that computes the element of an integer array `a` plus 6 modulus 10 and store the result in array `b`. For example, if 5 is the second element of array `a`, then the second element of array `b` should be `(5+6)%10`, which is 1. The function has the following prototype, `n` is the length of the arrays, `a` and `b` are the integer arrays.

I did:

```
       void arithmetic (int *a, int n, int *b)
       {
         int *arr1; arr1=a; int *arr2; arr2=b; 

         int i;

         for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           *arr1 = *(((a + i) + 6) % 10);
           *arr2 = *arr1;
         }

         }//don't know if the function is correct.
```

Comment: Is what I did, correct?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1 problem -> operator precedence ...

Comment: Hello mr. @Asimi, are you saying in the this line *arr1 = *(((a+i)+6)%10); I will fix it.

Comment: `arr1` never changes in the first loop so you assign all of the results to the same place.

Comment: You mean `*arr1 = *(((a + i) + 6) % 10);`     `*arr2=*arr1` I can do these in the same place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things:

- No need to update the actual content of the first array (which fixes the error pointed out about your code always storing the result in the first element of `a`)
- Use some parens to make sure you get the right order of operations.

  ```
  void newArr(int *a, int n, int *b) {
      int *arr1; arr1 = a; int *arr2; arr2 = b;

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          *(arr2 + i) = (*(arr1 + i) + 6) % 10;
      }
  }
  ```

Think about your title "`...using Pointer arithemtic`".  You need to add the loop counter to the array pointer for both `arr1` and `arr2` so that it steps through each element of each array: `*(arr2 + i)` and `*(arr1 + i)`.

Comment: Glad to help.  I don't know if you are using pointer arithmetic for a specific assignment or not, but accessing array elements via `arr[i]` instead of `*(arr + i)` is generally cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

No, your function is not correct.

```
*arr1 = *((a+i)+6)%10);
```

1. You are only writing the values in the first element of the array.
2. `arr1` points to `a` which already has the values. You want to do the
   calculation with a value stored in `a` and then save it to `b`, so don't modify
   `a`.
3. `*((a+i+6)%10)` is completely wrong. `a+i+6` is the same as `&a[i+6]`. The `%10`
   applies to the value `&a[i+6]` (which is the address of the `i+6`th element), and returns a value between 0 and 9 (let's call
   it `x`). When do `*(x)` you are interpreting the `x` as a pointer and it
   dereferences (=access the value through the pointer) it, but this is not a valid
   address at all. You will also eventually access `a` out of bounds.
4. `*arr2 = *arr1;` here you also only storing the values in the first element of `arr2`.
5. You function has no name.
6. `int *arr1; arr1=a;` this is unnecessary, you can access `a` directly, no
   need to create a copy of the pointer.

The `+6 % 10` rule applies to the values stored in the array, not the indices.

The correct function should look like this:

```
void compute(int *a, int *b, size_t len)
{
    if(a == NULL || b == NULL)
        return;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        b[i] = (a[i] + 6) % 10;
}
```

And if your assignment says you should do it with pointer arithmetic instead of
using array indexing:

```
void compute(int *a, int *b, size_t len)
{
    if(a == NULL || b == NULL)
        return;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        *(b+i) = (*(a + i) + 6) % 10;
}
```

Comment: Hello Pablo! I know you. Sorry I accidently deleted my function name when I was editing. Quick question, isn't size_t is more for strings? How does this fits for an integer array? Just curious?

Comment: @Ulta `size_t` is a type that you should use for indexing or storing quantities that are positive, like the length of an array or the length of a string.

Comment: am I right to assume that size_t also takes care of conflicting types when there are multiple types in a program?

Comment: @Ulta I don't understand what you mean. Like I said, `size_t` is an unsigned numeric type. Functions like `strlen` return a `size_t`, the `sizeof` operator returns a `size_t`.

Comment: Sorry for vagueness, I meant variable types. I thought when using size_t, size_t automatically adjusts to different variable types in a function. I may of have to learn about this topic, regardless. Thank you Pablo, i bet one day i will be answering your question ;)

Comment: @Ulta no, `size_t` is just another type like `int` or `float`. If the types are compatible with `size_t`, then the compiler won't warn you.

Comment: i see. `Size_t` has to be a part with same types. Otherwise just like every variable type, issues would occur. I got you sir :)

Comment: @Ulta yes, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

This is also a good place to reinforce the fact that the pointers are passed by value and that the function receives copy of each pointer which it is free to iterate with to affect the copy without effecting the pointers in the caller. So it would also be perfectly valid to do:

```
void arithmetic (int *a, int *b, size_t n)
{
    if (!a || !b)
        return;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++, a++, b++)
        *b = (*a + 6) % 10;
}
```

(good job Pablo with the use of `size_t` for the length (or number of elements) parameter)

Comment: Sure, There is always more to learn in C. Even after 20 years. Good luck with your coding and enjoy the ride.